# How to add multiple model objects on the same admin page Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

The idea is super simple. This is specific to my project, I want to add data to 2 objects of the same model on one Django admin page and have one save button.

My class:

```
class Data(models.Model):
issuer = models.ForeignKey(Issuers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
issuer_field = models.ForeignKey(Fields, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
data_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
long_term_ar = models.IntegerField()
section_1 = models.IntegerField()
short_term_ar = models.IntegerField()
short_term_investments = models.IntegerField()
cash = models.IntegerField()
```

To illustrate:[I want to have 2 of those on the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJN7E.png)

I am new to Django, and it will be super helpful if you will help me implement this idea

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on "Inlinemodeladmin objects": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

You will be able to add more than one record at the same time:

[image]

Comment: This helped, but it's actually a different way that's better, thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. I am still learning Django too. However, I believe that you dont need to specify the save instance since it is already built in django.

models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
issuer = models.ForeignKey(Issuers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
issuer_field = models.ForeignKey(Fields, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
data_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
long_term_ar = models.IntegerField()
section_1 = models.IntegerField()
short_term_ar = models.IntegerField()
short_term_investments = models.IntegerField()
cash = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Data

class DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('issuer', 'issuer_field')


admin.site.register(Data)
```